# Xcode UI Testing (Objective C): find element by Accessibility Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-ui-testing

My app under test has an element (a `UIAStaticText`) which has accessibility enabled (with the accessibility-label "Progress").

Accessing this element using Swift is easy and well-documented. But my app's source is in Objective C.

How do I access this element using Xcode UI Testing and Objective C?

Comment: You can use swift in your UI Testing module and objective-c for your project code. Both can work hand in hand.

Comment: Any idea or references as to how? The only results I got when I searched, involved a lot of "hacking".

Comment: I have my code in objective-c and use swift for UI Testing. You simply need to add UI Testing module and select swift as its language. I use [this tool](https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot), it also has a lot of references listed in the section "getting started", that should help you around.

Comment: Wow I so should try this. Thanks and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way to do this. This does get me the correct element - but I *feel there has to be a simpler answer that does not rely on me knowing the element's type (staticText)*.

If anyone has a better answer, you are welcome to contribute.

```
XCUIElement *progressTextByAccessibility = [[app staticTexts] elementMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeStaticText identifier:@"Progress"];
```

Comment: I ended up moving to Swift. Apparently it is possible :) while it did not directly solve my problem it worked well enough.